# I have a Source file with comma delimiter and I want to change it to pipe delimiter

Tags: unix

Some of the values inside the column we are getting with comma, So when we are trying to convert to pipe delimiter the values are also getting converted to pipe which should not happen.

Eg :

```
Name,claimid
Sandeep,kumar,12
mohan,reddy,13
```

**Required Output**:

```
Name,Claimid
Sandeep,kumar|12
mohan,red|13
```

I have tried using sed command , but the value inside the Name column is also getting changed to pipe delimiter . Could any one please help

```
sed 's/,/|/g' <filename>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are sure you want to replace the second `,`, you can use

```
echo "Name,claimid
Sandeep,kumar,12
mohan,reddy,13" | sed 's/,/|/2'
```

When you arre sure you want to change the `,` before the last field with digits, you can use

```
echo "Name,claimid
Sandeep,kumar,12
mohan,reddy,13" | sed 's/,\([0-9]\+\)$/|\1/'
```

Comment: Hi @Walter A,
Could you  please help me to the below question also, there are 6 columns in the source file with comma as delimiter and the output should be in Pipe Delimiter.
 Example:claim_name,claim_description,prvd_name,name,claim_id,Adress 
**Values:**  Insurance,car,,judge,krishna,reddy,prasad,236545,HNO415

**Desired Output:** Insurance,car||judge,krishna|reddy,prasad|236545| HNO415

Comment: You can chain some sed commands like the first solution or search for some pattern like `echo "Insurance,car,,judge,krishna,reddy,prasad,236545,HNO415" | sed -r 's/([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*)/\1,\2|\3|\4,\5|\6,\7|\8|\9/'`